# How to create a job in Rundeck that triggers REST URL?

Tags: job-scheduling, rundeck

There is a REST endpoint doing some automation work. I need to run it from Rundeck as a JOB. Is it possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, for example, you can use the [HTTP Workflow Step Plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) plugin to call any API REST URL in the same way of cURL. Or just call directly (using [cURL](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) on command step or inline-script/script steps).

I leave this job definition example (with the HTTP Workflow Step plugin way) that uses the [httpbin](https://httpbin.org) testing service:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>f953870e-efbb-4144-bea4-7432c4733710</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <step-plugin type='edu.ohio.ais.rundeck.HttpWorkflowStepPlugin'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='authentication' value='None' />
            <entry key='checkResponseCode' value='false' />
            <entry key='method' value='POST' />
            <entry key='printResponse' value='true' />
            <entry key='printResponseToFile' value='false' />
            <entry key='proxySettings' value='false' />
            <entry key='remoteUrl' value='https://httpbin.org/anything' />
            <entry key='sslVerify' value='false' />
            <entry key='timeout' value='30000' />
          </configuration>
        </step-plugin>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>f953870e-efbb-4144-bea4-7432c4733710</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Here the same thing but using script step:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>908fae13-1282-4584-b8bf-2f626c605cfe</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[curl -s -X POST "https://httpbin.org/anything" -H  "accept: application/json"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/sh</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>908fae13-1282-4584-b8bf-2f626c605cfe</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRO5R.jpg) the result.